# Include subset of nuget package in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

I have 2 projects in my solution, a web project and a class library.

The web project has a nuget reference for a [popular CMS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms/). Now, I would like to include the CMS ORM (its petapoco implementation), which is a subset of the nuget package. How would I include only some of the dll:s from the package in my class library.

If I add a the CMS nuget package to both projects, my class library gets cluttered up with a lot of unnecessary view folders etc. which is what I would like to avoid. Is this possible? If I reference the desired dll:s directly from the class library, can I be sure that they're always compiled before the class lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of installing the full Umbraco CMS package, you can install the [Umbraco Core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UmbracoCms.Core/). Its description states (bolding mine):

> Contains the core assemblies needed to run Umbraco Cms. This **package
>   only contains assemblies** and can be used for package development. Use
>   the UmbracoCms-package to setup Umbraco in Visual Studio as an ASP.NET
>   project.